# Hello World with using Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I've been studying examples of Threads and Handlers in Android - a new concept for me. I thought I would start simple with Hello World. I took some snippets from other people's code to see if I could make it work but I'm not really sure what I'm doing. Code is posted below. Could someone share some advice? I just want the Hello World to display a second or two after the app launches. So what am I doing wrong?

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

private Handler handler;
private Runnable r;
private TextView hello;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);

     handler = new Handler();
     handler.post(r);
     Runnable r=new Runnable()

     {

    public void run() 

        {
            hello.append("Hello World This is A Thread");                       
        }
     }; 

    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hello_world, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `TextView` named `hello` has not been intialized. Also Handler and Thread are two differents concept. The way you are using the handler is the same to write

```
hello.append("Hello World This is A Thread");
```

inside the `onCreate` of your `Activity`.

after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world)`;

you have to init your `TextView`

```
hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloId);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, totally didn't see that it. I seriously suck at the obvious.

Comment: happens every time you start something new. Next time will be better